# HTML page with sources from IPv6 and IPv4 only

Tags: javascript, css, html, ipv6

I have an HTML5 page available through IPv4 or IPv6.
Css style and JavaScript is available from other domains only via IPv4.
It does not work for pure IPv6 connection.

Will it work well for connections that both IPv4 and IPv6 can do?
Can it be a problem, for example, in some browsers?

Comment: "It does not work for pure IPv6 connection." - no, it only means it doesn't work for IPv6 users without a functioning 6to4 configuration, which isn't your responsibility.

Comment: If you currently link to resources such as jQuery hosted on external sites, consider hosting the copy of jQuery (or whatever) on your own site. Then it will always be available to every visitor.

Comment: Resources are hosted In this case on other domains for an easy update. Not JQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this will eventually be a problem. IPv6-only clients are still rare today, but they do exist, and as time goes on, they'll become more and more commonplace. This is independent of browser, so if one of your users suffers from this, switching browsers won't help them.

Comment: OK, I'm mainly asking for a connection that supports IPv4 and IPv6 at the same time.

Comment: Problems won't occur in that case. All browsers are happy to download resources over IPv4 if available, even if the site itself was accessed over IPv6.